# How to keep Selenium Webdriver browser open in Python3 when driver is called in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

I have this weird issue where I can't keep the Chrome webdriver open if the code is inside a function or a class. Even if I don't call the quit() function on the driver.

Here's the function

```
def driver_open():
   mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "iPhone 6"}
   chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vaio\Dropbox\PyCharmProjects\Nagora\chromedriver.exe",                       
   desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())
   driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
   return
```

However, the browser stays open if I run the same piece of code outside a function, in a simple script like this one:

```
mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "iPhone 6"}
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver =webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vaio\Dropbox\PyCharmProjects\Nagora\chromedriver.exe",
                      desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Even if I run the two pieces of code in the same python file, the Google page browser stays open (because the code is outside a function or class) whereas YouTube page closes automatically when the DOM finishes loading.

I tried countless solutions, but none of them work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function definition closes with return and hence the driver variable is lost too, but when you do it outside the function, the driver definition is still open.

The way around to this is to use the 'detach' option when starting chromedriver.

In your case add :

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

The same functionality can also be achieved using IDE breakpoints, not recommended though.